# DecimalFormat behaving strangely with 0.0 BigDecimal

Tags: java

I'm working with currency, taking a pipe delimited file, performing mathematical transformations on it and saving it as a CSV file. The output currency must match the format of 17 digits and 2 decimal points. As such I am using a DecimalFormat: `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00000000000000000.######");`

If I have a non-zero currency I wish to append to a `StringBuilder` via:

`sb.append(FormatString(df.format(event.value), true));`

where `FormatString` is:

```
private String FormatString( String value, boolean addDelim)
{
    value = value == null ? "" : value.replace(delimiter, "");

    if (addDelim)
        value += delimiter;

    return value;
}
```

The output is fine; a value which was `-256.07` is `-00000000000000256.07` etc. However, if a value is `0.0` it is represented as `00000000000000000` with no decimal points.

Why is this?

Comment: Sorry, what is `delimiter` in this case?

Comment: The source file? `|`

Comment: Gosh, I must be blind. You explained that part on the first line. Sorry about that

Comment: You can change `00000000000000000.######`to `00000000000000000.00` - # means a digit, but if that digit is 0, then it will exclude it. You can use 0 instead of #.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` suppresses any non-significant digits. A pattern of `"00000000000000000.0#####"` would ensure `.0` at the end, even if the decimal part doesn't have any non-zero digits.